# getting generic interface in java

Tags: java, hibernate, generics, reflection

I read somewhere that it's impossible to get generic interface of a class in run time. so how does hibernate do this? for example in a OneToMany mapping how does hibernate find out the Many part class (using annotation)?

```
class A{
    ...
    @OneToMany(mapped-by="a")
    public List<B> getBs(){ 
    ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I read somewhere that it's impossible to get generic interface of a class in run time.

It depends. You can't ask an instance of a generic type what its type arguments are - but you *can* get that information from the metadata about classes, method return types etc.

So for example, [`Method.getGenericReturnType`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#getGenericReturnType%28%29) returns a `Type` rather than a `Class<?>`, and that lets you get at the relevant information.

Sample code:

```
import java.lang.reflect.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Method method = Test.class.getMethod("getList");
        Type returnType = method.getGenericReturnType();
        System.out.println(returnType); // java.util.List<java.lang.Integer>
        ParameterizedType parameterized = (ParameterizedType) returnType;
        System.out.println(parameterized.getActualTypeArguments()[0]);
    }    

    public List<Integer> getList() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you have a class declaration like `class X implements Foo<String>`, you can get the concrete type arguments (here "String") for implemented interfaces via `getGenericInterfaces()` and `getGenericSuperclass()`.

Comment: When inspecting generics or subclasses thereof i found Guava's TypeToken veeeery useful.

Answer (score 0):

Class contains meta data which stores **SOME** generic information.